# Laravel Nova action that doesn't depend on items

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a table that comes from IoT device, so I have a lot of data.

I want to create an action to check that data is consistent and that I have no missing data depending on 3 params.

My problem is the action is only showing when I select at least 1 item from resource list.

Is there a way to trigger an action without having to select items from the list ?

Comment: hope it helps but not sure this answer is actually what you need.

Comment: unfortunately not. I will also make a cron job for that, but I want to be able to trigger it from laravel nova UI when needed.

Comment: Then I think you should use websocket along with cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want a Laravel Nova Detached Action.

Check out https://github.com/gobrightspot/nova-detached-actions

Comment: Yep, I guess I do !

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron job to accomplish this purpose. You can create an Artisan command to check missed items and add it to cron entry on the server. [Please check this documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling)

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\CheckMissedItems;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use \DB;


class CheckMissedItems extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'check_missed_items:fire';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle()
    {
       $missingItems = DB::table("test")->where("status", false)->count();
       if($missingItems) {
          // TODO what you need.
       }
       // TODO what you need.
    }
```

After that add this Artisan command to schedule `App\Console\Command\Kernel.php`

```
$schedule->command('check_missed_items:fire')->daily();
```

Finally add `php artisan schedule:run` to cron entry on the server.

```
> crontab -e
```

Add this command

```
   * * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

By doing this, your artisan command runs daily in background.